# Can I invoke an event handler programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I would like to call the following event handler from within another function without having to split the code out into another function:

```
$('#welcome select').change(function () {...});
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, you can [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the change event.

```
$('#welcome select').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/). This seem to be what you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
function handler() {
    // do stuff
}
$('#welcome select').change(handler);

handler();
```

Comment: > *without having to split the code out into another function*